# process part of json file

Tags: java, genson

I've got a `json` file that looks like this

```
{
  "races": [
    {
      "name"  : "ORC"
    },
    {
      "name"  : "HUMAN"
    },
    {
      "name"  : "ELF"
    }
  ],
  "npc": [
    {
      "race"  : "HUMAN",
      "age"   : "25",
      "name"  : "Jerome"
    },
    {
      "race"  : "ORC",
      "age"   : "26",
      "name"  : "Rz'Ul"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve the data from `races` or `npc` separately on demand. I am using `genson` to parse `JSON`. I parse it like this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> readJsonList(String listName) {
    Genson genson = JsonContext.PARSER.getParser();
    List<T> result = null;
    try (InputStream is = JsonDataProcessor.class.getResourceAsStream(FILE)) {
        ObjectReader reader = genson.createReader(is);
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();

            if ("races".equals(listName) && "races".equals(reader.name())) {
                result = (List<T>) processRaceData(reader);
                break;
            }

            if ("npc".equals(listName) && "npc".equals(reader.name())) {
                result = (List<T>) processNpcData(reader);
                break;
            }

        }
        reader.endObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And for example the method to parse `races` looks like this

```
private static List<Race> processRaceData(ObjectReader reader) {
    List<Race> raceList = new ArrayList<>();
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        reader.next();

        Race race = new Race();
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();

            if ("name".equals(reader.name())) { race.setName(reader.valueAsString()); }
            else { reader.skipValue(); }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        raceList.add(race);
    }
    reader.endArray();
    return raceList;
}
```

In debug it `populates` variable `result` just fine, but on `endObject` line I get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonStreamException: Illegal character at row 11 and column 4 expected } but read ',' !
        at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.newWrongTokenException(JsonReader.java:942)
        at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.end(JsonReader.java:428)
        at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.endObject(JsonReader.java:177)
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.json.JsonDataProcessor.readJsonList(JsonDataProcessor.java:41)
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.Example.prepareDb(Example.java:18)
        at com.lapots.breed.platform.Example.main(Example.java:23)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where do the JsonContext + JsonDataProcessor classes come from?

Comment: @hammerfest `JsonContext` is an enum that returns instance of `Genson` while `JsonDataProcessor` is the class that contains the method from the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with your code and found that **genson** is expecting to close object and check `}` symbol when you call `endObject`. You just need to skip object with `reader.skipValue()`. So error is in your `while` block in `readJsonList` method. This piece of code should work good for you:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public static <T> List<T> readJsonList(String listName) {
 . . .
 while (reader.hasNext()) {
     reader.next();
     if ("races".equals(listName) && "races".equals(reader.name())) {
         result = result = (List<T>) processRaceData(reader);
         break;
     }
     if ("npc".equals(listName) && "npc".equals(reader.name())) {
         result = result = (List<T>) processNpcData(reader);
         break;
     }
     reader = reader.skipValue();
 }
 reader.endObject();
 . . .
```

Comment: Well it works by only for single entry `races`. It ends loop after the first iteration. I guess I should investigate `genson` more.

Comment: @user1432980 I thought that this is what you want. You cannot have several `races` entries in the same hierarchy level in JSON. It would be not valid JSON file. Didn't I answered you question?

Comment: Yup indeed, I had some issues with `process` methods so it populated data only for `race` entry and not for others, as I fixed it it successfully processed json as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the data-binding capabilities of Genson and let it do the skipValue and mapping for you?
You could define two data structures, one for races and another one for npc and then deserialize to them like this:

```
class Races {
  public List<Race> races;
}

class Npcs {
  public List<Npc> npc;
}

// This will skip npc and all the fields in it
Races races = genson.deserialize(inputStream, Races.class);
```

This remains pretty efficient and less error prone than writing the deserialization using the low level streaming API.